# List element: allow multiple editos

Tags: list, item-level-permissions

Under the **advanced list settings** I'm able to limit the editing of elements only for those who are listed as creators of the list element.

Is it possible to have more than one "creator" of a list element which gives the possibility to edit an item in a list? (editing should be possible for visitors, not only site owners which can - by default - see and edit everything).

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes you are referring to the **Advanced setting**, **Item-level permissions**.

When **Create and Edit** access is set to **Create items and edit items that were created by the user**, the following roles can edit:  1) The user who created the item, 2) users assigned Full Control, and 3) users assigned Design.

When **Create and Edit** access is set to **Create and edit all items**, the following roles can edit:  1) The user who created the item, 2) users assigned Full Control, and 3) users with a minimum of Contribute.

[image]